# If indian currency is selected, show in billing address country “india” only

Tags: magento-1.9, magento1.9.3

If a user selected "indian" currency, and in checkout page billing address show only "india" in country list.

How can i do this ?

please help me someone. I am using magento 1.9.3.9

Answer (score 1):

Go to

> Configuration => General, set "Default Country" as "India".

Hope it will help you !

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, but i am not mean this.  If in a user login and he selected the currency as "indian currency", in checkout page address  country list, show india only. don't show other country. But if a user select "USD as currency", we can show all countries in country list in checkout page address

Comment: I thing you should customize function show countries in checkout

Comment: do you know how ?? which file ??. i am totally new in magento, and trying to find out this. if you know plz help me...

Comment: oh, will take time for customize, I can do it. If you want, you can contact with me

Comment: i solved this, by making two store view. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Configuration => General, set "Default Country" as "India". and  Allow Countries select India only.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but i am not mean this.  If in a user login and he selected the currency as "indian currency", in checkout page address  country list, show india only. don't show other country. But if a user select "USD as currency", we can show all countries in country list in checkout page address